# How can I distinguish wheel button click event from mouse press event?

Tags: qt, event-handling, pyside

I am wondering how i can distinguish wheel click event from mouse press event. Because i want to do different handling for these two events in pyside. Currently, every time I click the wheel button, the event is catched by mousepressevent. Can anyone explain ?

Edit: I want to implement this in a subclass of 
qglwidget class

Comment: The wheel is probably interpreted as middle button click?

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld  The wheel is interpreted as scroll not middle button click. When i write a event handling function for wheel middle button click in wheelEvent, mouse Press gets the middle button click event

Comment: @Johnnylin. That's exactly how it's supposed to work. A mouse wheel can be used for both scrolling **and** clicking. Most modern mice have three click-buttons, and many have five. You can distinguish between them by examining the `button()` and/or `buttons()` methods of a [QMouseEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmouseevent.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From its name, the `mousePressEvent` is responsible for mouse clicks while the `wheelEvent` is for scrolling solely. The `wheelEvent` will not catch the wheel button click. It is how the Qt's API is designed when it comes to mouse events processing.

In order to separate which mouse button is pressed (right, wheel or left), use `button` [property of `QMouseEvent`](https://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMouseEvent.html#PySide.QtGui.QMouseEvent).

This is how the code would look like using C++ (I imagine it is easy to translate it to `pyside`)

```
void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) // redefine the mouse event
{
switch( event->button() ) {
case Qt::LeftButton:
    // do stuff for left button pressed
    break;
case Qt::MiddleButton:
    // do stuff for wheel button pressed
    break;
// ...
}
}
```

So, for pyside, you only need to compare the `button` property of `event` in `mousePressEvent` and see whether it is `Qt.LeftButton` , `Qt.RightButton` or `Qt.MidButton`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I want. And, can you help explain what is use of event filter ? Because I thought I should use an event filter to distinguish them.

Comment: An example usage of an event filter is to be able to control events when dealing with multiple `QObject`s - assume some parent object contains a child and you want to process child's events from a parent. In this case, you'd set up the event filter `childObject->installEventFilter(parent)` and then in the `parent::eventFilter()` you can process `child`'s events while being the `parent`. Refer to [this more concrete example](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405544&seqNum=2) if more details are needed.